# If an image has an onload that calls a function defined in an async script, is there a chance of race condition?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, race-condition

I have a script in the header that's set to load "async":

```
<script src="/scripts/myscript.js" async></script>
```

I also have an image on the page that calls a function when it loads:

```
<img onload="MyObject.start()" src="/images/img.jpg" />
```

While my initial tests have all ran without issue, that doesn't guarantee me that there isn't a race condition and a possibility of the script loading too late.

Is there a requirement/standard that guarantees the `async` loaded script will be parsed prior to anything that needs it (or at least prior to image `onload` being called)?

Comment: It's hard to imagine how the browser could guarantee anything, since the timing is out of its control.

Comment: If recommend `defer` instead of `async` http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html

Comment: @Hackerman Won't the onload call fail with defer?

Comment: @Hackerman Also, the article you linked disagrees with you: `When should I use what? Typically you want to use async where possible, then defer then no attribute.`

Comment: If you want to avoid race conditions, you should prefer `refer` instead of `async`...the article is just to point and clarify :)

Comment: `•If the script relies upon or is relied upon by another script then use defer.`

Comment: @Hackerman That won't work for an image onload call

Comment: Did you try it, right?...if you try it and doesn't work, then, my mistake....